# how to add a pseudo-element gradient effect

Tags: css

Hello how could i add to a pseudo-element gradient effect from left to right.
i'm trying:

```
.divider p:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 25%;
    z-index: -1;
    border-top: 1px solid #666666;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="divider">
 <p><span>Featured</span></p>

 </div><!-- end of divider -->
```

above code draws a sharp line,but i would like create something like this:

[image]

my whole code was:

```
.divider {
color: #666666;
}
.divider p span {
margin:0;padding: 0 10px;
background: #FFFFFF;
display: inline-block;
}
.divider p {
padding-left: 20px;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;   
}
.divider p:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 0;
right: 25%;
z-index: -1;
border-top: 1px solid #666666;
}
```

Comment: You may want to clarify what you mean by "pseudo-element gradient effect."

Comment: it draws a shap line,but i would like it to be gradient like this.http://3.bp.blogspot.com/--mnE6qvKvuQ/VM0nYdKASnI/AAAAAAAAAGI/5QIfWHza3PM/s1600/Screenshot_2.png

Comment: It's drawing a sharp line because there is a border being applied to the element

Answer (score 8):

```
.box:before,
.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: -10px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 50%;
}

.box:before {
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #333 0%, transparent 100%);
}

.box:after {
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333 0%, transparent 100%);
}
```

Comment: Elements with `position: absolute;` behave like block elements. Therefore, you can do without `display: block;`

Answer (score 1):

In response to Bergmann's question to the original answer:

You could simulate solid gradient borders with little extra css.

HTML:

```
<div class="element">
    <div class="content">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.element {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
}
.element:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #000 0%, #fff 100%);
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    background-color:white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nu9zmxvw/

In this sample the .element padding is used to simulate border.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the other questions here, I would like to add that it's possible to simply apply a gradient to the `content` property directly, because it's a "must" property in pseudo-elements, so it's shorter to use it instead of additionally writing `background`:

```css
body::after {
  content: linear-gradient(purple, yellow);
  
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

This is only applicable if the `content` property shouldn't have a value anyway.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content#element_replacement_with_gradient

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work consistently in all browsers. In Firefox gradient does not show. Possibly because image dimensions are not specified (image is contained in pseudo-element and does not have dimensions, it does not take dimensions of the box).

Comment: @Lovor - There's an [open bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1832901) on this, you can **vote** it to add more attention on it